# How to exit debug session on Borland C++ Builder 6?

Tags: c++, ide, c++builder-6

While mid debugging, what's the proper way to force exit debug mode. I didn't see the usual red square "stop" button like visual studio or eclipse.

Comment: You can customize the IDE's toolbar. There is a Stop button, so you probably just don't have it placed on your toolbar. Right-click on the Toolbar and customize it as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe key combination "Ctrl+F2" can help you.